# Jquery cycling between two functions

Tags: jquery, triggers, cycle

Hi I'm making a toggler which has to cycle between two functions, just learned how to do it with an unique trigger:

```
jQuery.fn.clicktoggle = function(a, b) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    jQuery(this).bind("click", function() {
        if (clicked) {
            clicked = false;
            console.log(clicked);
            return b.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        clicked = true;
        console.log(clicked);
        return a.apply(this, arguments);
    });
  });
}
jQuery("myTrigger1").clicktoggle(myOpen, myClose);
```

This works OK when I have a unique trigger, i.e. "myTrigger1"... But how can do it within two triggers?

```
jQuery(".myTrigger1, .myTrigger2").clicktoggle(myOpen, myClose);
```

The cycle is not working well... When I click one of the triggers, it toggles between the two functions open and close, but if click the other trigger when the action is "myOpen", I have to click twice...

What if I had 3 triggers to do the same?

The functions "myOpen" and "myClose" are not jQuery.toggle functions, they some code inside.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution by attaching a class to an element that can be checked from inside the function:

```
jQuery('.myTrigger1, .myTrigger2').on('click', function (event) {
    jQuery('.myDiv').toggleClass('toggled');
        if (jQuery('.myDiv').hasClass('toggled')) {
            myOpen();
        } else{
            myClose();
        }
})
```